# Quarkus reactive route: a catch all endpoint is catching the health endpoints

Tags: quarkus, health-check, smallrye, quarkus-reactive

I have a quarkus project to receive webhooks. For this kind of application it is important to return `2xx` even in case of an unexpected request. Otherwise the webhook sender often retry and send the same request again:

So I have added a generic catch-all rule:

```java
    @Route(path = "/*", order = 2)
    public void other(RoutingContext rc) {
        String path = rc.request().path();
        Log.warnf("Invalid path '%s' ", path);

        rc.response().setStatusCode(200)
            .putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE.toString(), "application/json")
            .end("{{\"status\": \"error\"}}");
    }
```

But now in the same project I also had `io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-health` and my catch all is also catching the requests to:

- `/q/health/live`
- `/q/health/ready`

How can I make my catch all rule to come after the *health" endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see with which order the default health endpoints are registered in [`SmallRyeHealthProcessor.java`](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/30ffd97b351fdff899c72175e5d0d6c398905bfc/extensions/smallrye-health/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/smallrye/health/deployment/SmallRyeHealthProcessor.java#L208-L224).

So I ended up doing something calling `rc.next()` for the endpoints in question:

```java
    @Route(path = "/*", order = 2)
    public void other(RoutingContext rc) {
        String path = rc.request().path();
        if (path.startsWith("/q/health")) {
            // the module 'quarkus-smallrye-health' will answer:
            rc.next();
        } else {
            Log.warnf("Invalid path '%s' ", path);
            
            rc.response().setStatusCode(200)
                .putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE.toString(), "application/json")
                .end("{{\"status\": \"error\"}}");
        }
    }
```

But I am not sure if this is state of the art Quarkus development.